# recording 8k videos on android

Tags: android, android-camera

How to record 8k Videos on android from 3rd party camera app?
I am referring especially to the samsung s20 serie.
If I check the supported video sized - all I get is 4K.

```
StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
android.util.Size[] sizeList = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
```

Comment: Presumably, Samsung does not support that video format, at least for third-party apps. Bear in mind that their own apps could use private APIs to work with the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer say that they do not suppport 8k for now.

> Hi ,  4K is maximum output supported at this moment for 3rd party
> developers using available APIs, unfortunately. We will pass this
> requirement to the relevant team to consider it for the future.
>
> Please let us know if we could help you further.
>
> Best Regards, Samsung Developer Program

[image]